# Show alert instead of redirect to Internal Server Error page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there some way that I can show alert instead of the 500 Internal Server Error page? I have a predict button and whenever I click on that button I want to show an alert instead of redirecting me to another page and showing the error. This is my ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myButton").click(function(){
        var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
        var canvasObj = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var img = canvasObj.toDataURL();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/predict/",
            data: img,
            error: function(err) {
                alert('Error'+ err);
            },

            success: function(data){
                $('#result').text(' Predicted Output: '+data);
            }
        });
    });

    });
```

And this is my html:

```
 <form id="predictbutton" action="/fourthtask/predict" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <!--        <input type="file" name="image" value="Upload">-->
                <input class="btn btn-success myButton" type="submit" value="Predict">
            </form>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

EDIT: 
I am doing the error in purpose because that is how the tool is intended to work, but I don't want to show to the user the 500 internal server error page but rather I want to show it as an alert or modal. The server-side is in flask.

Comment: You're submitting a form and the server-side code is failing for some reason. The correct thing to do is fix the error.

Comment: I know that whenever a condition is reached I get that error, and I'm doing the error in purpose but the point is to display that error as a modal or alert not redirect me to another page. For the server-side I am using flask

Comment: You've got a "submit" button in a `<form>`. Your event handler does not prevent the default action, which is for the browser to submit the page and reload the window with whatever the response is. Simplest thing to do would be to change the button to type "button", or use a `<button type=button>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The result is being shown as a new page because you are submitting the form.

This has nothing to do with the success or failure of the request.

The form will always submit and always display the result as a new page.

If you want to prevent it submitting so the Ajax request can run, then you need to prevent the default behaviour of the submit button:

```
$(".myButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
```

Comment: I tried this but it is preventing to click the button at all and I only need to prevent the default behaviour of the submit button, if error otherwise if success it has to submit.

Comment: You can either submit the form and have native handline of the response **or** make a request with JavaScript and handle the response with JavaScript.